# AWS RDS: transaction level in Aurora replica

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, transactions, isolation-level, amazon-aurora

We are using Amazon Aurora as a database for our web application.
we set the transaction level to READ-COMMITTED for our primary instance by creating new  parameter group and attaching it to the primary instance to avoid locks.
By default amazon replicas are using transaction level as REPEATABLE-READ by using default instance parameter group. 
When replica is promoted as primary instance in case of failures, our primary instance's  transaction level is changing to(TRANSACTION ISOLATION=REPEATABLE-READ ).
we wanted to set the transaction level to READ-COMMITTED instead of REPEATABLE-READ when replica(reader) is promoted as primary instance(writer). it would be great if anyone provide a way to achieve this.

Comment: You guys figured this out?

Answer (score 0):

This capability was added in 2019. It requires setting the session-level configuration parameter aurora_read_replica_read_committed. The details are in the docs here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Reference.IsolationLevels.html#AuroraMySQL.Reference.IsolationLevels.relaxed